# What's $GLOBALS['wp_settings']['media']['embeds']?

Tags: core

In `wp-admin/options-media.php`, there are a few lines that go:

```
<?php if ( isset( $GLOBALS['wp_settings']['media']['embeds'] ) ) : ?>
<h3 class="title"><?php _e('Embeds') ?></h3>
<table class="form-table">
<?php do_settings_fields( 'media', 'embeds' ); ?>
</table>
<?php endif; ?>
```

'embeds' and "embeds" are nowhere else to be found in the WP code base. Might anyone know what it's for?

Comment: Weird one. Introduced in [changeset 21998](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/21998).

Comment: Looks like it was actually leftover from previous WP versions: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21719

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the two comments by Rarst and myself, the variable itself is is potentially populated by `add_settings_field()`, and the related logic is present for historical/backwards compatibility reasons. (There used to be fields in this area.)

The related ticket and changeset for reference:

- http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21719
- http://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/21998